# How to make this script work but search for empty files in any directory instead of current directory?

Tags: file

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
for f in *; do
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && { echo "$f"; ((n++)); }
done
echo :Number of empty files: $n"
```

currently it checks the current directory for empty files, I would like it to search for empty files in any directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Recursively searches for empty files in current directory and below:

```
find . -empty -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively lists empty files in specified directory and below and reports total

**findempty**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo :Number of empty files: `find $1 -empty -type f | tee /dev/tty | wc -l`
```

**Example Usage**

```
findempty /tmp
```

**Example Output**

```
/tmp/source/fb/b
/tmp/source/fb/a
/tmp/source/fb/c
/tmp/source/fa/b
/tmp/source/fa/a
/tmp/source/fa/c
/tmp/source/fc/b
/tmp/source/fc/a
/tmp/source/fc/c
/tmp/dest/source/fb/b
/tmp/dest/source/fa/b
/tmp/dest/source/fc/b
:Number of empty files: 12
```